# Missing artifact com.sun:tools:jar:1.4.2

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, installation, build

While building java project in eclipse, I am seeing error "Missing artifact com.sun:tools:jar:1.4.2"
And I am unable to proceed mvn clean install of the project.
Does anybody resolved this issue before?

Answer (score 0):

com.sun.tools.jar is not sufficiently properly licensed to be capable of even being in the mavencentral repo. It's also.. 20 years old. Presumably someone in the project either adding that to their local clone of mavencentral or otherwise modified things so that it does exist, or, someone at some point added it to mavencentral, and since then it has been removed due to licensing issues.

com.sun.tools is, primarily, `javac`. Most likely you're using JSP (another 23 year old obsolete tech you really don't want to be using in 2022) which needs this. Upgrade things, from the context of your question it's not clear what, but it's 20 years out of date, whatever it is.

NB: More recent versions of java *are* sufficiently licensed, I believe, also, java has a built in way to get a compiler which doesn't require a separate dep. So it's not just a matter of 'okay which maven group/artefact/version DO I use'. Whatever code needs this needs some slight reworking.

Comment: The 30 years old part is not accurate https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language)

Comment: Huh, it's only 20 years. Not sure the gist of the message fundamentally changes, though. Editing...